# mysqli_query insert doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
$marka = $_POST['marka'];
$model = $_POST['model'];
$godiste = $_POST['godiste'];
$cena = $_POST['cena'];

$query = "INSERT INTO `auto` (`id`, `marka`, `model`, `godiste`, `cena`) VALUES (NULL, '$marka', '$model', '$godiste', '$cena');"

if(mysqli_query($connection,$query)) {
    echo "New record created";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . mysqli_error($connection);
}
```

I can't find what is problem here:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in C:\wamp\www\autoplac\forma.php on line 16

Comment: Put a `;` after `$query = "INSERT INTO auto (id, marka, model, godiste, cena) VALUES (NULL, '$marka', '$model', '$godiste', '$cena');"`

Comment: Okaay, this is awkward fail .. thank to everyone..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not stuff user-input values into query strings.  The usual reason given is SQL injection -- and that is an important reason.  An even better reason is that you can get unexpected syntax errors, because the content of the string interferes with the rest of the query.

It is easy enough to use parameters.  Start with `mysqli_prepare()`.  Here is a place in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) to start.

Comment: This is really a suggestion/comment. The actual issue here is the misplaced semi-colon in `'$cena');"` causing the parse error. `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)...`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the semicolon AFTER the Double cuote in the query sentence

Answer (score -1):

Missing ; on end of line

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `auto` (`id`, `marka`, `model`, `godiste`, `cena`) VALUES (NULL, '$marka', '$model', '$godiste', '$cena');"
```

should be

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `auto` (`id`, `marka`, `model`, `godiste`, `cena`) VALUES (NULL, '$marka', '$model', '$godiste', '$cena');";
```